# using custom variables or functions inside a makeStyle()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

Im working on a React Material Ui component currently.

currently the goal is to be able to change JSS styling according to some custom function or values in another part of the application, without needing to add / remove classes

This is my current setup:

**stepControl.js**

```
const stepControl = () => {
    const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0)
    const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(new Set())
    const [stepCount, setStepCount] = useState(0)
    const completedSteps = () => {
        return completed.size
    }
    const totalSteps = () => {
        return stepCount
    }
    const allStepsCompleted = () => {
        return completedSteps() === totalSteps()
    }

    return {
        state: {
            activeStep,
            completed
        },
        actions: {
            totalSteps,
            completedSteps,
            allStepsCompleted,
            setActiveStep,
            setCompleted,
            setStepCount
        }
    }
}

export default stepControl
```

**index.styles.js**

```
import { makeStyles } from '@tim/functional'
import stepControl from './stepControl.js'

const useStyles = () => {
    const { state, actions } = stepControl()

    return makeStyles(theme => ({
        root: {
            width: '70%',
            margin: 'auto',
            '& .MuiPaper-root': {
                backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            '& .MuiStepConnector-lineHorizontal': {
                borderTopWidth: 6,
                borderRadius: 1,
                marginTop: -2,
                borderColor: actions.allStepsCompleted()
                    ? theme.palette.primary
                    : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24)
            }
        },
        button: {
            marginRight: theme.spacing(1)
        },
        backButton: {
            marginRight: theme.spacing(1)
        },
        completed: {
            display: 'inline-block',
            '& .MuiStepConnector-lineHorizontal': {
                borderTopWidth: 6,
                borderRadius: 1,
                borderColor: theme.palette.primary
            }
        },
        instructions: {
            marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
            marginBottom: theme.spacing(1)
        }
    }))
}

export default useStyles
```

Currently im getting too many rerenders error even if i just return a fixed value in the function in question **allStepsCompleted()** . how would i go about doing this in Material Ui?

Im running:

- React 16.9
- Mui 4.9.5
- on a webpack 4.4 server on macOS 10.15

Thanks in advance for any suggestions